# How to label a whole dataset?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, conv-neural-network

I have a question.I have a pandas dataframe that contains 5000 columns and 12 rows. Each row represents the signal received from an electrocardiogram lead. I want to assign 3 labels to this dataset. These 3 tags belong to the entire dataset and are not related to a specific row. How can I do this?

I have attached the picture of my dataframe[pandas dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUytY.png).

and my labels are: Atrial Fibrillation:0,
right bundle branch block:1,
T Wave Change:2

I tried to assign 3 labels to a large dataset
(Not for a specific row or column)
but I didn't find a solution.

As you see, it has 12 rows and 5000 columns. each row represents 5000 data from one specific lead and overall we have 12 leads which refers to this 12 rows (I, II, III, aVR,.... V6) in my data frame. professional experts are recognised 3 label for this data frame which helps us to train a ML Model to detect different heart disease. I have 10000 data frame just like this and each one has 3 or 4 specific labels. Here is my question: How can I assign these 3 labels to this dataset that I mentioned.as I told before these labels don't refers to specific rows, in fact each data frame has 3 or 4 label for its whole. I mean, How can I assign 3 label to a whole data frame?

Comment: Your question is unclear and lack details, please provide a data sample **as text**, pictures are not acceptable. Also explain carefully the logic with an example and provide the complete expected output.

Comment: Thanks for your consideration. I added more detail about my question. I'm new to stack overflow community and I could not provide my data sample as text, the font just messed up, but I will try to solve that.

Comment: Provide a sample of your dataframe not as a picture, also, your question is still unclear. Please explain what you want to achieve?

Comment: My dataframe does not have labels. I want to achieve a dataframe with 12 rows and 5000 columns which has 3 labels. I already have the labels but I don't know how to assign the labels to my dataframe in order to use supervised learning method to train my neural network.

Comment: Each row should be labeled (or whatever you want to call sample), assigning labels to the whole dataset does not make sense for supervised learning.

Comment: thanks @Dr.Snoopy your comment clearly enlightened my mind.